# Windows batch: get substring of variable length in loop

Tags: windows, string, loops, variables, batch-file

I would like to retrieve a substring of variable length in a for loop as follows:

```
@ECHO off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
CALL :strlen orglength %cd%
FOR /F "DELIMS==" %%d in ('DIR /AD /B /S') DO ( 
SET a=%%d
CALL :strlen curpatlen !a! ::sets curpatlen the length of string a
SET /a l=%orglength%-!curpatlen!

::crucial part: get the last l characters of a
CALL SET curpat=%!a:~!l!!% ::doesnt work

ECHO !curpat!
)

:strlen <resultVar> <stringVar>
(   
set "s=!%~2!#"
set "len=0"
for %%P in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
    if "!s:~%%P,1!" NEQ "" ( 
        set /a "len+=%%P"
        set "s=!s:~%%P!"
    )
)
)
( 
set "%~1=%len%"
exit /b
)
```

The main idea:
Starting in the directory X of the batch file, I create a folder named X-svg (not part of the code I posted on purpose). Then, I go through all subdirectories of X looking for .pdf files which I want to convert to .svg files(future work). For all subdirectories of X which contain a .pdf I want to create a corresponding folder in X-svg that contains only the converted .svg file. In order to create the corresponding folders in X-svg, my idea was to keep the string length of the directory of X-svg in orglength, compute the length of the current path X/Y and the difference between both in order to be able to create the folder X-svg/Y, into which I would then convert the available .pdf.

What I would like to do in the code above: given a length orglength of a path string org, I want to get the difference string between org and the current path, %%d, which avries witch each loop. An example with static substring length of 4 would be:

```
REM FOR loop over %%d
set str=%%d
set str=!str:~-4!
```

In my case, instead of 4, I need a variable length which is calculated during the for loop.

Thank You in Advance

Edit: This code works for me:

```
@ECHO off
CALL :changefolder %cd% "svg"
xcopy "%cd%\*.pdf" "%Result%\" /T /S
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('cd') do (
     set foldername=%%~nxA
)
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "DELIMS==" %%f in ('DIR "*.pdf" /B') DO (
        set varpdf=%%f
        set var=!varpdf:~0,-3!
        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Inkscape\inkscape.exe" -f !varpdf! -l %Result%\!var!svg
    )
FOR /F "DELIMS==" %%d in ('DIR /AD /B /S') DO (  
    set PassedString=%%d
    call set tempstring=%%PassedString:\%foldername%\=\%foldername%-svg\%%
    FOR /F "DELIMS==" %%f in ('DIR "%%d\*.pdf" /B') DO (
        set varpdf=%%f
        set var=!varpdf:~0,-3!
        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Inkscape\inkscape.exe" -f %%d\!varpdf! -l !tempstring!\!var!svg
    )
)
endlocal
goto :eof

:changefolder
set Path1=%~1
set Path2=%~2
if {%Path1:~-1%}=={\} (set Result=%Path1:~-1%%Path2%) else (set Result=%Path1%-%Path2%)
goto :eof
```

May not be best but works

Comment: Some examples would be good. Your current version attempts to use a `::`-style remark in a block, which is always a bad idea. You are attempting to set something within that loop and reports its value, but there's no indication of what or why. You're asking for a fix to unexplained code. Reaching a label in batch doesn't terminate the process - so `strlen` will simply be re-entered when the `for /f` has terminated. You've mentioned `.pdf` and `.svg` but these strings don't appear in your code. Please explain what substring you are attempting to extract. There is likely to be a much simpler way

Comment: sorry, I hope I could answer all Your questions in the correction. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this to see if it creates the folders that you need:

```
xcopy "x:\main\folder\*.pdf" "c:\x-org\" /T /S
```